# Apache Web Server 2.4 - Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-14.04

Hopefully someone can help me, and many thanks in advance.

I have set up an Apache Web Server 2.4 on Ubuntu machine with reverse proxy from my server (www.mypage.de) using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to https://www.google.de/.

My URL in the header is constantly on www.mypage.de and I am on google.de. Everything is fine so far.

What do I have to set up when I want to use www.google.de/privacy on my page www.mypage.de/privacy.

In easy words, when I type www.mypage.de/privacy in the browser, it should linked to www.google.de/privacy but without changing the URL in the header.

ServerName mypage.de

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/key"

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass / https://google.de/
ProxyPassReverse / https://google.de/
```

Answer (score 0):

For my geo location, the first thing I see on https://google.de/privacy is a HTTP 301 https://www.google.de/privacy

Your ProxyPassReverse doesn't catch that. You need to catch all the possible redirect locations:

```
ProxyPassReverse /  https://google.de/
ProxyPassReverse /  https://www.google.de/
ProxyPassReverse /  https://www.google.com/
ProxyPassReverse /  https://who.knows.what.else/
```

Furthermore, HTTP 301 is permanently stored by browser, which means that for most browsers you need to clear the cache to retry your test.